# How to check whether a unicode character can display well in an Android device

Tags: android

How can I know whether an unicode (\u263a) will displayed well in an Android device. I use robotto thin font (bundled together with APK). The character displayed well in my Nexus S 4.0, but not emulator 2.3

For instance, if ☺ cannot displayed well in an Android device, I will replace it with :)

Comment: How do you define "displayed well"? If your objective is solely emoticons, you might consider using a dedicated font for those.

Comment: "displayed well" mean it doesn't show up as a square rectangle. It displayed as what it suppose to be.